# Gridview attributes from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I set the OnRowDataBound method name from code behind?

Aspx code:

```
OnRowDataBound = "gvResults_RowDataBound"
```

How to set that from code behind?

```
gvResults.Attributes["OnRowDataBound"] = "gvResults_RowDataBound";
```

does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `RowDataBound` event handler from the GridView:

```
gvResults.RowDataBound += gvResults_RowDataBound;
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks, but it is just gvResults.RowDataBound right?